# Jquery Error parsing Json data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm having an error parsing a JSON response from PHP.

Javascript:

```
function getStock()
{
    var color = $("#select_color option:selected").val();
    var comp = "<?= $idComp ?>";

    $.post( "ajax/getStock.php", 
    { 
        idColor: color, 
        idComp: comp 
    }).done(function( data ) 
    {
        alert(data);
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $('#stockReal').val(obj.StockReal);
        $('#stockMinimo').val(obj.StockMinimo);
        $('#stockMaximo').val(obj.StockMaximo);
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    require_once "../../helper/db.php";
    require_once "../../helper/security.php";

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
    {
        if(!empty($_POST['idColor']) && !empty($_POST['idComp']))
        {
            $idComponente = test_input($_POST['idComp']);
            $idColor = test_input($_POST['idColor']);


            $conn = db_connect($STOCKMANAGER);

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM TableStock
                    WHERE idComponente = '$idComponente'
                    AND idColor = '$idColor';";
            $stock = db_request_one($conn, $sql);

            if($stock !== 0)
            {
                $respuesta = array('StockReal'=>$stock->StockReal
                    ,'StockMinimo'=>$stock->StockMinimo
                    ,'StockMaximo'=>$stock->StockMaximo);
                echo json_encode($respuesta);
            }
            else
            {
                $respuesta = array('StockReal'=>''
                    ,'StockMinimo'=>''
                    ,'StockMaximo'=>'');
                echo json_encode($respuesta);
                //echo $respuesta;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

The error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...    jquery-1.10.2.js:550
```

When I get data from alert for example I get:

```
{"StockReal":"33","StockMinimo":"0","StockMaximo":"55"}
```

This is a good Json data. But if I try to validate with http://jsonlint.com/ i get the next error message:

```
Parse error on line 1:

^
Expecting '{', '['
```

Also when I try to stringify the Json Data I get a lot of `u0000\` before and after the data.

like this:

```
"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000{\"StockReal\":\"33\",\"StockMinimo\":\"0\",\"StockMaximo\":\"55\"}\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please tidy up your post, it's very off putting (for me at least). Also, please post the JSON that you tried validating in jsonlint

Comment: the JSON looks fine and i have validated it in                       http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: yes now jsonlint.com validate it when you copy/paste from stackoverflow, but when i copy/paste from alert dialog (aparently same data) i´m having this parsing error.

Comment: try using dataType as "json" in AJAX call and remove the parseJSON part.

Comment: Pawal, when i change as "json" i got same error 

Error: Error: parsererror ErrorText - SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: hd. here you have again the Json data that fails for me in jsonlint.com:

{"StockReal":"33","StockMinimo":"0","StockMaximo":"55"}
but is tested that if i copy/paste from stackoverflow is working ok... strange...

Answer (score 0):

Have you done an output of what is returned from `$respuesta` array? `print_r($respuesta)` and see what's in your array.

Also make sure you have NO white space in your `getStock.php` file.

Comment: Thanks Big Chris,
when i do print_r($respuesta) and i have no data i´m receiving this:
Array
(
    [StockReal] => 
    [StockMinimo] => 
    [StockMaximo] => 
)

but when i´m getting data i have nothing printed by print_r($respuesta)